# Close Chrome window after oAuth exchange

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I have code that opens a window

```
let mywindow = window.open("utl", "title", "resizable=yes,width=600,height=400,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes");
```

I want to access the current URL of the window, I have tried:

- window.location
- window.document.url

Every try returns:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://mail.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at eval (eval at  (chrome-extension://dapaeellgmlagjcopljjcfiadalafdil/extension.js:57053:21), <anonymous>:1:10)
>       at chrome-extension://dapaeellgmlagjcopljjcfiadalafdil/extension.js:57053:21

I am doing an oAuth token exchange, when the window hits the redirect URI, I need the window to be closed automatically.

What are the ways in which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) API, here is an example:

```
const orgURL = '<URL>';
chrome.tabs.create({url: orgURL}, createdTab => {
   function updateListener(tabId, tab) => {
     if (tabId == createdTab.id && tab.url !== orgURL) {
        const redirectURL = tab.url;
        // Do something with the redirect URL
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabId); // Close the tab.
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(updateListener);
     }
   }
   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(updateListener);
});
```

Don't forget to add the `chrome.tabs` permission to the manifest.

If you really want to do this using a new window instead of a new tab in the current window, take a look at the [`chrome.windows`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) API.

Here is an example using the `chrome.windows` API:

```
const orgURL = "<URL>"
chrome.windows.create({ url: orgURL }, win => {
  if (win.tabs.length) {
    const firstTab = window.tabs[0];
    if (firstTab.url !== orgURL) { // the redirect already happen
       const redirectURL = window.tabs[0].url;
       // Do something with the redirect URL
    } else {// the redirect hasn't happen yet, listen for tab changes.
       function updateListener(tabId, tab) => {
         if (tabId == firstTab.id && tab.url !== orgURL) {
           const redirectURL = tab.url;
           // Do something with the redirect URL
           chrome.windows.remove(win.id); // Close the window.
           chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(updateListener);
         }
       }
       chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(updateListener);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried this with the `chrome.windows` API but the URL of the window/tab is not updated, so the URL property is not changed. Is this expected? How can I get the current URL from the window?

Comment: @SanketDG I'm not sure why that is, you're probably adding the update listener (`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`) after the redirect (after the URL changed). To get a tab's URL you can use this: `chrome.windows.create({url: ....}, win => console.log(win.tabs[0].url))`, basically, once the new window is created access the first tab (`win.tabs[0]`) and check its `url` property.

Comment: @SanketDG I've edited my question to add an example using the `chrome.windows` API.